# AngularJS keeps sending Invalid Request when resource not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, playframework-2.0

Say when I want to pull a collection of images via AJAX and display them in the page using ng-repeat.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="submission in submissions">
                    <a href="/entry/{{submission.slug}}" class="submission-thumb">
                      <img src="{{submission.thumbnail_url}}">
                    </a>
                    <a href="/entry/{{submission.slug}}" class="submitter-avatar">
                      <img src="{{submission.profile_picture_url}}" width="42"/>
                    </a>
</li>
```

The problem is with the above image source tags above. It keeps sending these below invalid requests to the server before the collection get pulled in and causing error messages in the logs file.

```
GET http://localhost:9000/campaign/%7B%7Bsubmission.profile_picture_url%7D%7D 404 (Not Found) test:138
GET http://localhost:9000/campaign/%7B%7Bsubmission.thumbnail_url%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Anyway to prevent this to happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `ng` values will keep this from happening:

```
<a ng-href="/entry/{{submission.slug}}" class="submission-thumb">
    <img ng-src="{{submission.thumbnail_url}}">
</a>
```

Also, I wouldn't use `width` like that:

```
<img src="{{submission.profile_picture_url}}" width="42"/>
```

It's preferable to do with CSS (better through a class):

```
<img src="{{submission.profile_picture_url}}" style="width:42px;" />
```

Source: [AngularJS: ng](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng)

Comment: Granted using `width` is still OK... you have much more flexibility through CSS.